# Unmarshal yaml incorrectly?

Tags: go, yaml

I am using [yaml](https://github.com/go-yaml/yaml) to decode yaml file. However, the result is not as expected.
The `EncryptKey` is not extracted. This is my test code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "gopkg.in/yaml.v2"
)

var data = `
port: 8080
encryptKey: "jfgjfgkfgd"
`

type Config struct {
    Port       int    `json:"port"`
    EncryptKey string `json:"encryptKey"`
}

func main() {
    t := Config{}

    err := yaml.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &t)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error: %v", err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("--- t:\n%v\n\n", t)
}
```

I got the result like this:`--- t:
{8080 }`

---

It's my carelessness. I should use the tag `yaml` instead of `json`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `json` tags instead of `yaml` tags. Fix your struct definition like this:

```
type Config struct {
    Port       int    `yaml:"port"`
    EncryptKey string `yaml:"encryptKey"`
}
```

Comment: Hey, no problem. Glad I could help.